# ADB Problem that can't lanch my project in the AVD, Please give me a hand

Tags: android, debugging

[image]

before the problem, I run an other project in the Nox emulator, and I used the command "nox_adb connect 127.0.0.1:62001" , after finding answer, i use the command "nox_adb kill-server" and in the direction of the sdk's platform-tools "adb start-server",but the avd can't reply to the run command,that the avd always waiting for all device to come online

Comment: welcome to so, [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.